# What is this feature on a Sukhoi Su-27?

Tags: military, fighter, feature-identification, russia, su-27

Most but not all Russian Su-27's (and variants like the Su-30, -32, -33) have a device that looks like a headlight in front of the cockpit. What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the sensor of the IRST (**I**nfra**R**ed **S**earch and **T**rack) system.
An IRST allow an aircraft to search and track aerial or ground targets using passive infra-red radiation only thus reducing the probability of being discovered (for example using a Radar Warning Receiver).

The Su-27 can use it's IRST to track a target at very long distance and engage it using IR homing AAMs like the R-73 "Archer" or the R-27T / R-27ET "Alamo" without using its radar.

Nowadays, many current fighter aircrafts use some sort of IRST, for example the Eurofighter Typhoon.

[image: Typhoon's IRST sensor]

Answer (score 7):

That is the [IRST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infra-red_search_and_track) which can be used for tracking aircraft passively.